# When using TFRecord, how can I run intermediate validation check? (a better way?)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I defined a network `Net` and the example code below runs well.

```
# ... input processing using TFRecord ...     # reading from TFRecord
x, y = tf.train.batch([image, label])         # encode batch
net = Net(x,y)                                # connect to network

# ... initialize and session ...
for iteration:
    loss, _ = sess.run([net.loss, net.train_op])
```

The `Net` does not have `tf.placeholder`, since input is provided by tensors from TFRecord provider. **What if I would like to run validation set as well**, e.g., every 500 steps? How can I switch input flow?

```
x, y = tf.train.batch([image, label], ...)      # training set
vx, vy = tf.train.batch([vimage, vlabel], ...)  # validation set
net = Net(x,y)

for iteration:
    loss, _ = sess.run([net.loss, net.train_op])

    if step % 500 == 0:
         # graph is already defined from input to loss.
         # how can I run net.loss with vx and vy??
```

Only one thing I can imagine is, modifying `Net` to have placeholders, and every time running like

```
sess.run([...], feed_dict = {Net.x:sess.run(x), Net.y:sess.run(y)})
sess.run([...], feed_dict = {Net.x:sess.run(vx), Net.y:sess.run(vy)})
```

However, this seems to me that I lost benefits of using TFRecord (e.g., full TF integration). In the middle of computation flow, I have to stop the flow, run `tf.sess`, and continue (doesn't this lower speed by forcing to use CPU in the middle?)

I am wondering,

1. if there is a better way.
2. if my solution is not that worse than I imagine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way (than placeholders). I ran into this issue with the CIFAR10 tutorial in TensorFlow, which I adjusted to check accuracy on the test set simultaneous to the training every 500 batches or so. This is where sharing variables comes in handy.

```
x, y = tf.train.batch([image, label], ...) # training set
vx, vy = tf.train.batch([vimage, vlabel], ...) # validation set

with tf.variable_scope("model") as scope:
  net = Net(x,y)
  scope.reuse_variables()
  vnet = Net(vx,vy) 

for iteration:
  loss, _ = sess.run([net.loss, net.train_op])

  if step % 500 == 0:
    loss, acc = sess.run([vnet.loss, vnet.accuracy])
```

By setting the scope to reuse variables on the second call to `Net()`, you will use the same tensors and values created in the first call but with a different set of inputs. Just make sure that vimage and vlabel aren't reusing tensors from image and label (which could possibly solved by creating their own variable scopes).

Comment: Deeply thanks, @jpm! It seems much better, and I would definitely try. Before trial, I have one thing to make sure. As far as I remember, in order to use `reuse_variables`, you should define variables using `tf.get_variable()` instead of `tf.Variable()`, right? (Luckily, I am usually using `tf.get_variable()`)

Comment: Did my answer prove successful? `tf.get_variable()` is the function needed when using variables that might be shared, so yes it is a good thing if you're using that in `Net()`. I'm not sure if you can share variables with `tf.Variable()`

Comment: It seems to work! Thanks again. Nevertheless, may I ask one more (less relevant) question? I have a pretrained weights in a checkpoint file. However, due to the new variable scope, since all tensor names are having the "model/" prefix, I cannot restore weights from the file. Did you have a similar problem?

Comment: Hmm I didn't ever come across that, but I think there might be two ways to handle this. Hopefully the easy way would be to swap `tf.variable_scope("model")` with `tf.get_variable_scope()` and see if that works. Otherwise a simple one-time fix might be to rebuild your exact graph under the scope "model" but initialize each of the tensors with the pre-trained weights and then save the "model" weights. Let me know what works for you!

Comment: Thanks, @jpm. The first one works! Although tf.get_variable_scope() seems not compatible with the `with` statement, I could do `tf.get_variable_scope().resuse_variables()`. However, "avoiding placeholders" is still questionable, because if I do this, (1) tensorboard graph visualization is more complex (since there are two branches anyway) (2) summaries (like loss value) from `train` and `val` are more hard to handle. How do you think? Is it still worthy?

Comment: Good to know! And those are good points, I actually spent a lot of time removing summaries that were causing a bunch of errors in my CIFAR10 model on account of having multiple scopes for similar weights. You are probably right that it might not be worth it.

Comment: I see. Nevertheless, thanks for enlighting me and sharing your experience again. I learned a lot from this thread.